# How can I write variables so I don't have to repeat myself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using an animated modal called animatedModal.js

In order to have a modal fire on click, I have to register a new ID and class every time I need a new Modal. I'm writing this as static HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I don't want to register 49 classes and IDs when I know there's a more DRY way of doing so. How can I write this code so it finds classes and IDs and passes them into a function?

```
<div class="item box student-life"> 
    <a class="demo2" href="#animatedModal-2"> 
        <img class="responsive-img" src="img/design-3-cards-buttons-icon-update-final-design-TILES3_07.jpg">
          <div class="content-card">
            <h3 class="title">This is an example of a long headline. They Happen sometimes but, I won't let them destroy my layout. Not this time.</h3>
            <h5 class="title">Service Learning</h5>
            <div class="icon"><img src="img/icons/student-life.png" class="responsive-img" alt=""/></div>
            <button class="btn pull-right">Read More</button>
          </div>
     </a> 
 </div>

<!--DEMO02 Window-->
<div id="animatedModal-2"> 
  <!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID  class="close-animatedModal" -->
  <div class="close-animatedModal-2">CLOSE MODAL</div>
  <div class="modal-content"> <img class="responsive-img" src="img/ART-01024.jpeg">
     <h1>Content for this block</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#demo01").animatedModal({
    animatedIn:'zoomIn',
    animatedOut:'bounceOut',
    color:'#39BEB9',
    beforeOpen: function() {

        var children = $(".thumb");
        var index = 0;

        function addClassNextChild() {
            if (index == children.length) return;
            children.eq(index++).show().velocity("transition.expandIn", { opacity:1, stagger: 250 });
            window.setTimeout(addClassNextChild, 200);
        }

        addClassNextChild();

    },
    afterClose: function() {
      $(".thumb").hide();

    }
});
```

Comment: `$("#demo01")` can be `$(".modals")`, and you can loop through a css selector's result in jq to dynamically add matching classnames to sub-tags based on the id of the parent, before running the modal maker.

Comment: Umm, what do the different ids look like?

Comment: ID to reference modalTarget

$(".demo2").animatedModal({
    modalTarget: 'animatedModal-2',
    position: "fixed",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                top: "0px",
                left: "0px",
                zIndexIn: "9999",
                zIndexOut: "-9999",
                color: "#39BEB9",
                opacityIn: "1",
                opacityOut: "0",
                animatedIn: "fadeInUp",
                animatedOut: "slideOutDown",
                animationDuration: ".6s",
                overflow: "auto",
  });